# Safely using shared_ptr and lambda callback with boost::asio

Tags: c++, boost-asio, shared-ptr

Here's a simplified version of my problem. I'm using `boost::asio`, and I have a function that processes some data passed into it, but I want to delay that processing by 5 seconds. This is how I've implemented it.

```cpp
void process_later(boost::asio::io_service& io, const std::string& data) {
    auto timer = std::make_shared<boost::asio::steady_timer>(io);
    timer->expires_from_now(std::chrono::seconds(5));

    timer->async_wait(
        [timer,data](const boost::system::error_code&) {
            std::cout << data << std::endl;
        }
    );
}    ​
```

I'm not entirely sure if this is safe or not, both in terms of undefined behaviour (e.g. free before use) and a memory leak of `timer`.

My gut feeling is that this is okay. The lambda capture creates a copy of `timer`, incrementing its reference count and keeping it above zero. The `boost::asio` stuff then holds a reference (copy?) of that lambda, which it keeps until the callback is executed 5 seconds later. It then destroys the lambda, which removes the last reference to `timer`. But there's a lot of speculation in there, which leads to this question.

Comment: *The boost::asio stuff then holds a reference (copy?) of that lambda* It does not hold a reference, it moves and owns the lambda. The solution above is not good if you imaging the main exits until 5 sec elapsed.

Comment: @S.M. Thanks for clarifying that. Moving and taking ownership of the lambda makes sense.

Can you elaborate your second point? This is just a snippet from a long-running program, so I don't think I'm worried about main exiting unless I'm misunderstanding your comment.

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly as you said and absolutely fine to manage the lifetime of your custom objects this way. You can look at the async asio [tutorials](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime3.html) for some advanced examples. They do not use lambas, but the basic workflow is the same: let asio handle the lifetime by storing shared pointers in completion handlers.